# Postfix getting wrong values in C

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, singly-linked-list, postfix-notation

So i am writing a postfix program in C using linked list and my output values are off, for example the expression:[ 3 4 5 * + 6 7 * 8 + 9 * + ]  should equal 473, but my program returns 4.
I also need to check for errors such as (2 3 - where there's no closing ). right now it ignores it and gives me a value.

My code is as below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Node to store data and address of next next
struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
} ;

// Stack type
typedef struct Stack
{
    int value;
    struct Node* top;
    struct Node* back;
} Stack;

// Stack Operations
struct Stack* createStack()
{
    Stack* stack = (Stack*) malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    if (!stack)
        return NULL;

    stack->top = NULL;
    stack->value = 0;

    return stack;
}

// check stack is empty or not
int isEmpty(Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->top == NULL;
}

// return peek of stack
int peek(Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->top->value;
}

/**
 * return top of stack and pop element from top of stack
 */
int pop(Stack* stack)
{
    char  top;
    if (!isEmpty(stack)) // no empty
    {
        top = stack->top->value;
        stack->top = stack->top->next;
        stack->value--;
        return top;
    }
    return -1;
}

/*
 * push an element into stack
 */
void push(Stack* stack, char  op)
{
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));

    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->value = op;

    if (isEmpty(stack))
    {
        stack->top = newNode;
        stack->value++;
        return;
    }

    newNode->next = stack->top;
    stack->top = newNode;
}


// The main function that returns value of a given postfix expression
int evaluatePostfix(char* exp)
{
    // Create a stack of capacity equal to expression size
    Stack* stack = createStack();
    int i, val, val2, res;

    // Scan all characters one by one
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(exp); i++)
    {
        // If the scanned character is an operand (number here),
        // push it to the stack.

        if (isdigit(exp[i]))
            push(stack, exp[i] - '0');


        // If the scanned character is an operator, pop two
        // elements from stack apply the operator
        else
        {
            val = pop(stack);
            val2 = pop(stack);

            switch (exp[i])
            {
            case '+':
                res = val2 + val;
                push(stack, res);
                break;

            case '-':
                res = val2 - val;
                push(stack, res);
                break;

            case '*':
                res = val2 * val;
                push(stack, res);
                break;

            case '/':
                res = val2 / val;
                push(stack, res);
                break;
            }
            push (stack, res);
        }
    }
    return pop(stack);
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    char exp [20];
    Stack* stack = createStack();


    printf("Enter postfix expression: ");
    scanf("%s", exp);


    printf ("postfix result: %d\n", evaluatePostfix(exp));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're pushing results twice. Remove the `push` calls inside the switch statement. I didn't check or test this though. Couple other asides: 1) your program is vulnerable to buffer overflow, 2) cache the result of `strlen` otherwise you wind up with O(n^2) runtime, 3) don't cast the result of `malloc` and 4) use `sizeof(*newNode)` instead of `sizeof(struct Node*)`.

Comment: I deleted the push inside the switch but still not correct.

Comment: OK, try to debug it then. For starters, have you validated that your stack is correct? Please share your minimization/debugging attempts and include your latest code. The double push is definitely incorrect so you'll want to fix that and explain where the new problem is. Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out, I got rid of my   'stack->value--' and  'stack->value++'

Comment: Good to hear! Feel free to post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or we can close it out as no longer reproducible.

Comment: Note that `scanf("%s", exp)` will stop at the first space — which is going to make it hard to enter consecutive numbers.  You should probably be reading whole lines using a function such as `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this structure definition

```
// Stack type
typedef struct Stack
{
    int value;
    struct Node* top;
    struct Node* back;
} Stack;
```

does not make a great sense. For example the data member `back` is not used. The meaning of the data member `value` is unknown.

There is no sense to define an object of the type Stack dynamically. So this function

```
struct Stack* createStack()
{
    Stack* stack = (Stack*) malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    if (!stack)
        return NULL;

    stack->top = NULL;
    stack->value = 0;

    return stack;
}
```

is redundant.

The function pop uses an object of the type `char` instead of the type `int` to return a value stored in the stack. An object of the type `char` is unable to store the positive value equal to for example `473`.

```
/**
 * return top of stack and pop element from top of stack
 */
int pop(Stack* stack)
{
    char  top;
    ^^^^^^^^^^
    if (!isEmpty(stack)) // no empty
    {
        top = stack->top->value;
        stack->top = stack->top->next;
        stack->value--;
        return top;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Also it does not free the popped node. So the function produces memory leaks.

The same problem tales place in the function push declared like

```
void push(Stack* stack, char  op);
                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Also you forgot to increase the data member `value` when the stack is not empty.

```
if (isEmpty(stack))
{
    stack->top = newNode;
    stack->value++;
    return;
}

newNode->next = stack->top;
stack->top = newNode;
// stack->value++; <===
```

The function `evaluatePostfix` should have the qualifier const with its parameter

```
int evaluatePostfix( const char* exp)
```

because the passed string is not changed in the function.

It is inefficient to use the function `strlen` in the for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(exp); i++)
```

Within the function you push a result of calculation twice under each case label and after the switch statement

```
        switch (exp[i])
        {
        case '+':
            res = val2 + val;
            push(stack, res);
            break;

        case '-':
            res = val2 - val;
            push(stack, res);
            break;

        case '*':
            res = val2 * val;
            push(stack, res);
            break;

        case '/':
            res = val2 / val;
            push(stack, res);
            break;
        }
        push (stack, res);
```

It is desirable to skip embedded white spaces in the string.

And as the stack was allocated dynamically you need to free it before exiting the function.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the program can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct Stack
{
    struct Node
    {
        int value;
        struct Node *next;
    } *top;
} Stack;

int push( Stack* stack, int  value )
{
    struct Node *newNode = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = newNode != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        newNode->value = value;
        newNode->next = stack->top;
        
        stack->top = newNode;
    }
    
    return success;
}

void pop( Stack *stack )
{
    if ( stack->top != NULL )
    {
        struct Node *tmp = stack->top;
        stack->top = stack->top->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

int isEmpty( Stack *stack )
{
    return stack->top == NULL;
}

int peek( Stack *stack )
{
    return stack->top->value;
}


// The main function that returns value of a given postfix expression
int evaluatePostfix( const char *exp )
{
    // Create a stack of capacity equal to expression size
    Stack stack = { NULL };
    int res = 0;

    // Scan all characters one by one
    for ( ; *exp; ++exp )
    {
        if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )*exp ) )
        {
            // If the scanned character is an operand (number here),
            // push it to the stack.

            if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char ) *exp ) )
            {
                push( &stack, *exp - '0' );
            }

            // If the scanned character is an operator, pop two
            // elements from stack apply the operator
            else
            {
                int val = peek( &stack );
                pop( &stack );
                int val2 = peek( &stack );
                pop( &stack );

                res = 0;
                switch ( *exp )
                {
                    case '+':
                        res = val2 + val;
                        break;

                case '-':
                    res = val2 - val;
                    break;

                case '*':
                    res = val2 * val;
                    break;

                case '/':
                    res = val2 / val;
                    break;
                }
                
                push( &stack, res );
            }
        }
    }
    
    if ( !isEmpty( &stack ) ) 
    {
        res = peek( &stack );
        pop( &stack );
    }
    
    return res;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *exp = "3 4 5 * + 6 7 * 8 + 9 * +";
    
    printf( "postfix result: %d\n", evaluatePostfix( exp ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
postfix result: 473
```

You could append the program with a code that will check whether a current symbol of the passed string is a valid symbol. That is whether the passed expression is correct.